# Can't install rocm

Tags: amdgpu, amdgpu-pro

I would like to install ROCm on my ubuntu server.

I followed the tutorial here : https://rocm.github.io/ROCmInstall.html#installing-from-amd-rocm-repositories

I get these errors when I execute one of these commands :

- /opt/rocm/bin/rocminfo  : 
  `hsa api call failure at line 900, file: /home/jenkins/jenkins-root/workspace/compute-rocm-rel-1.9/rocminfo/rocminfo.cc. Call returned 4104`
- /opt/rocm/opencl/bin/x86_64/clinfo : 
  `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cl::Error'
  what():  clGetPlatformIDs
  Aborted`

I googled it a bit and tried some solutions proposed but I couldn't fix it and I don't really know how to get further...

I guess you will need some information on my setup :

- Ubuntu server : Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
- gpu : RX580

Could you please help ?

Kind regard

Answer (score 0):

If you are not in the `video` group, then adding yourself to it may fix the problem. To do that, run:

```
sudo usermod -a -G video $LOGNAME
```